# django - "auth_files_fileid_id" is an index

Tags: python, sql, django

I have the following models.py

```
class FileIndex(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    filetype = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    vendorid = models.IntegerField()
    vendorname = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    tablename = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'file_index'
        verbose_name = 'File/Vendor Index'
        verbose_name_plural = 'File/Vendor Indicies'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.filename

class UserFile(models.Model):
    userid_id = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    fileid_id = models.ManyToManyField(FileIndex)
    grant_date = models.DateTimeField()
    revoke_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_files'
        verbose_name = 'User File Matrix'
        verbose_name_plural = 'User File Matricies'

    def get_userids(self):
        return "\n".join([u.pk for u in self.userid_id.all()])

    def get_fileids(self):
        return "\n".join([f.pk for f in self.fileindex.all()])
```

I then run the following view in my views.py -

```
class ExampleView(APIView):
    model = cdx_composites_csv
    serializer_class = cdx_compositesSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        if UserFile.objects.filter(fileid_id=1, userid_id=2).exists():
            content = {
                'status': 'Request Successful.'
            }
            return Response(content)
        else:
            content = {
                'status': 'Request Failed.'
            }
            return Response(content)
```

It fails with the following error message -

```
"auth_files_fileid_id" is an index
```

The SQL it's trying to run is the following -

```
u'SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "auth_files"
INNER JOIN "auth_files_fileid_id" ON ( "auth_files"."id" = "auth_files_fileid_id"."userfile_id" )
INNER JOIN "auth_files_userid_id" ON ( "auth_files"."id" = "auth_files_userid_id"."userfile_id" )
WHERE ("auth_files_fileid_id"."fileindex_id" = 1  AND "auth_files_userid_id"."user_id" = 2 ) LIMIT 1'
```

If I were to write the query in the DB this is how it would look - for some reason the query is waaaaaay off and I'm unsure why it's registering like above.

```
select * from auth_files af
inner join auth_user on au.id = af.userid
inner join fileindex fi on fi.id = af.fileid
where fi.id = 1 and au.id = 2
```

Looking at the query that Django is creating it's trying to inner join on itself I have no idea why.

This is ultimately what I want the query to be -

```
select fi.filename from auth_files af
inner join auth_user on au.id = af.userid
inner join fileindex fi on fi.id = af.fileid
where fi.filename = 'filename' and au.username = 'testuser'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want those queries, then you have the wrong relationship type (not to mention your **extremely** odd field names). You're describing a foreign key relationship, but you have declared a many-to-many. M2M relationships require a linking table, which Django automatically names with the source table + fieldname - but apparently this conflicts with an index you have defined.

I would change those very strange fieldnames into something more standard ("users" and "fileindexes" would do fine) and recreate the database.

**Edited** As confirmed by the comments, you do have the wrong field type here. UserFile is already the linking table of a many-to-many relationship, so you need to use ForeignKey fields to both User and File. Again, though, you should use sensible names: each UserFile can only relate to *one* of each, so these names should be "user" and "file".

The many-to-many relationship is really from FileIndex to User, going through FileIndex, so you should declare it like that.

```
class UserFile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file = models.ForeignKey(FileIndex)
    ...
class FileIndex(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through=UserFile)
```

Comment: The reason for the manytomany is that the intermediary table called "UserFile" can have multiple references to User and also multiple references to FileIndex.  I agree this needs to be re-assessed from the beginning unfortunately I'm not drawing any working examples that are similar to see where my issue is.

Comment: Yes, that's what a M2M relationship does - but as I said explicitly, Django creates (and names) that table for you already. You do not need - and should not - try to reflect that name in your field. Remember, these are Python attributes, not db columns: what that field is representing is a set of Users, so you should call it "users".

Comment: Actually no, I see the problem. You're treating *UserFile* as your intermediary table. In which case, as I said originally, you should be using ForeignKeys, not many-to-manys.

Comment: Thanks!  ok so I had it right the first time!  It's something else that's causing my issue.  Marking as solved!

Comment: Thanks again!  I meant right the first time I was designing didn't have posted up here.  Originally I had 2 foreignkey in UserFile.  I never had the manytomany in FileIndex though.

Comment: Cool. You don't need that M2M necessarily, it just provides you with a nice accessor so you can do `my_file_index.users.all()` to get all the users related to a FileIndex instance.